# Find All Dependencies Necessary for an Emacs Install Without X

Tags: terminal-emacs, install, build

I'm building a script to install a version of emacs (24.5 in this case) on a small server running on a raspberry pi. Since this will be in headless mode, I have no need for a GUI/X windows based installation and will run the configuration with the `--without-x` flag.

That being said, how can I find all the dependencies needed by emacs24.5 (or in general) so that I can build a list for installation?

Further context:

1. Using Raspbian OS, I do not know how to get `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` to work as a command, so that is why I am asking for a list of these dependencies.
2. the recommendation from this [SX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627158/how-to-list-all-dependencies-of-a-package-on-linux) answer seems to be the closest to this, but `apt-cache depends emacs24-nox` seems to give a shallow answer in terms of dependencies. Is this all I really would need to put?

Comment: Looks about right, but why not just have `apt-get install emacs24-nox` as your script, maybe followed by `apt-get clean` to keep the space requirements down?

Comment: I agree that's a functional compromise, but it's just one of those things that I'm used to the packages built with 24.5 in mind that I want it. That said, I actually think I found a solution to get `build-dep` to work and will post it soon.

Comment: Annoyingly the SX answer has been deleted.